# Coloring pst-3dplot Surfaces

Tags: pstricks, graphs, pst-3dplot

I have drawn traces of the hyperbolic paraboloid z=y^2-x^2 using `pst-3dplot` as shown below:

[image]

I want to put color on this quadric surface to make it look more realistic. Is there a way to do this? (Basically, I want to produce a figure similar to the one below *(taken from Stewart Calculus' book)*:

[image]

I already tried using `\psplotThreeD` but the graph extends for values of z > 4 and z < -4. I wanted only the portion of the graph with x-values on [-4.472135, 4.472135] and the y-values on [-4,4] and the z-values to also lie on [-4,4] which is precisely what I graphed above. I know that `pst-solides3d` is an option but would like to stick to `pst-3dplot` for uniformity.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `˜pscustom` and then a continuous path for the different lines. For examples: The first plot has `(-3.46410 , 3.46410)` then the following should be `(3.46410 , -3.46410)`.  Same for the other coordinates.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. ☺️